# Source for Theory of Linear Transport equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, linear-pde, transport-equation

I'm looking for a source, like a textbook or something else that be used as a reference in a paper, for the theory of linear transport equations.

I want to have a proof of the well-known result that shows that the solution of these equations is given by the initial conditions composed with the solution of the characteristic system of ODEs.

All the results I need are for example perfectly represented in chapter 2 of [here](https://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/golse/M2/PolyKinetic.pdf). But unfortunately, that are just online lecture notes that I don't want to cite in a paper.

Comment: The  Cauchy Problem in Kinetic Theory by Robert T. Glassy published in SIAM covers a lot about the Vlasov equation in the linear and nonlinear cases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't found the basic theorems of chapter 2 in there and  I think this book is already too advanced. To clarify I'm not interested in Vlasov equations, but just the existence theory for linear transport equations with variable coefficients

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a PDE book which addresses the method of characteristics for (linear) scalar first-order equations in $n$ variables. There are few of them that could be used:

1. R. Courant, D. Hilbert, *Methods of Mathematical Physics: Partial Differential Equations*, Sec. 2.2, Wiley, 1962. [doi:10.1002/9783527617234](https://doi.org/10.1002/9783527617234)
2. L.C. Evans, *Partial Differential Equations*, 2nd ed., Sec. 2.1, AMS, 2010. [10.1090/gsm/019](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/gsm/019)
3. F. John, *Partial Differential Equations*, 4th ed., Sec 1.5, Springer, 1982. [10.1007/978-1-4684-0059-5](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4684-0059-5)

etc. See also references therein.